# Does anybody use an under the saddle bag for touring? (Not Pannier Bags)

Tags: saddle, bags

I am looking for a bag as an addition to my backpack to use for cycling. A pannier isn't a choice I want to make, because I believe they balance the weight badly, and that there is some risk of broken spokes on the rear wheel when using a pannier.

I started looking for other options and finally found this one:

Bag details:
Volume: 7 liters (1.85 US gal)
Weight: 250 g. (8.8 oz)
Material: “Titan”
Material density: 1680D
Basic colors: black or gray
Additional colors: orange, blue, yellow, red, green, light green, lime color.
Price: $59

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's fine for supported touring (in fact, more than you absolutely need), but likely insufficient for unsupported touring, unless you sleep in a bivy sack.

Comment: Also the weight isn't much further forward than for panniers - the main benefit would be in forcing you to pack less as it's so small.

Comment: How is a pannier a risk of spoke breakage or wrong weight balance?

Comment: How can you even consider using a backpack for serious touring? I am willing to walk with a backpack, but as soon as I use a bike I have the frame of the bike take the weight. By preference in panniers.

Comment: Just for the record, a proper rear rack and panniers will distribute weight *better* than either/both your backpack or saddle bag.  And the rack/panniers do not cause an increased risk of broken spokes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a survey (does anybody use these?) with no actual question.

Answer (score 4):

I have seen similar setups for MTB touring that use a large seatpack, a frame pack and a handlebar pack to get enough capacity. This setup also allows a better weight balance.

[Bikepacking.net](http://www.bikepacking.net)

is a good site for getting ideas for different setups. This site might also give you some ideas as well. I know we aren't supposed to recommend gear, but I've been very happy with the stuff I have got from Revelate Designs.

[Revelate Designs](https://www.revelatedesigns.com/index.cfm/store.catalog/Frame-Bags)

IMHO, your concerns about panniers are unfounded if you plan to tour on anything like a road. Panniers can be a problem if you are touring on trails or your bike geometry doesn't provide sufficient heel clearance ( often a problem on MTB bikes)

Comment: Many of the long distance snow racers aren't using panniers either.  You can get a lot in a framebag, large seat bag, and handlebar mount with better weight distribution.

Comment: Panniers on a snowbike could end up like being a giant snowplow. I can understand why they want the volume up high.

Comment: Usually not any more than the crankset.  There is a certain depth and consistency of snow where you just can't ride.  I think it's more about saving weight on a rack and the rack fittings in the bags.  Plus they have a tendency to detach in rough terrain and crashes.

Answer (score 4):

Saddle bags of different sizes used to be common for road bike touring in Europe. One popular brand was Carradice of Nelson. These days most people on similar trips seem to prefer small backpacks.

I personally used one for a supported trip through Switzerland. The bag was roughly the same size as yours, and it definitely interfered with bike handling. The bag is higher on the bike than panniers and swings around more. The good parts are that it was easy to install on a road bike that doesn't have the clearance or mounts for rear rack and because it's behind the rider, it doesn't increase air resistance.

Here's a picture (of Jobst Brandt) to give an idea about the setup:

[image: Jobs Brandt showing one]
<sub>(source: [joyfulathlete.com](http://joyfulathlete.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Jobst-Brandt.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I find bags like this just touch the back of my thighs and are irritating on anything more than a short ride.